# Rails integration tests with Faraday & Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, faraday

My integration test looks like this:

```
class OAuthTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  ...

  @client = OAuth2::Client.new(                                                
    client_id,                                              
    client_secret,                                          
    { :site => 'https://provider', :token_url => '/oauth/access_token' }
  )                                                                            

  @client.connection.build do |b|                                              
    b.adapter :action_dispatch, self
  end                                                                          

  access_token = @client.auth_code.get_token(...)
  access_token.get("/user.json")
```

And with Faraday 0.7.6 it works just fine, the `action_dispatch` adapter will route the http request to my Rails app (calling the `users_controller`). But with Faraday 0.8.0 the `action_dispatch` adapter was replaced by the `rack` (see https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/pull/134) and I cannot make it work.

I think I need to change the above code to this:

```
@client.connection.build do |b|      
  b.adapter :rack, self.app          
end
```

But it fails at Rack (1.2.5) expecting a Stream, but it gets a Hash and says `undefined read method for Hash` at line 149 (here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.2.5/lib/rack/request.rb#L149).

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add the middleware url_encoded to make this work;

```rb
@oauth = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret') do |b|
  b.request :url_encoded
  b.adapter :rack, Rails.application
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From your test suite you can access the rack app directly via the `app` variable. The code should be:

```
@client.connection.build do |b|      
  b.adapter :rack, app
end
```

I tried this out on [a sample app](https://github.com/jch/test_faraday_rails) and it's working for me.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it doesn't help me much... My `self.app` is the same as just `app`. The problem I see is that `@env["rack.input"]` in my case is a Hash. BTW: I'm on Rails 3.0.10 and I'm using Omniauth (this might have something to do with it, you know, omniauth does a lot of mumbo-jumbo behind the scenes). See it's initialization here: https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/client.rb#L48